# Load velocity view

Tags: spring-mvc, velocity, dispatcher

I have problem when using Velocity. I got this error when access "/my-website/login" link:

```
2014-04-07 16:50:48,900 16:50:48.900 [http-bio-8181-exec-3] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/my-website/WEB-INF/views/_layouts/login.vm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

My `LoginController.java` is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView index(HttpServletRequest request) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("_layouts/login");
    return model;
}
```

My web.xml is here

```
    ...
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.vm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/themes/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    ...
```

and the dispatcher.xml is

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.vm</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

So, what is problem? Please help me!

Comment: Are you trying to access the template directly?  That's what it looks like from the error message.  You should be hitting a mapped URL on a controller that in turn returns the proper template.

Comment: What URL are you accessing with the browser?

Comment: @CodeChimp I dont trying to access the template directly. I just want to use *.vm stead of *.jsp for view of SPRING.

Comment: Thats not what the settings you are showing are doing.  Those are creating an InternalResourceViewResolver that will take your returned view name and append the suffix of ".vm" to it, such that returning "myTemplate" would ultimately resolve to a file "/WEB-INF/views/myTemplate.vm".  To do what you are asking, simply change the `@RequestMapping` to have the extension you want, for example if you wanted the URL to be "/MyApp/widgets/getWidget.vw" you would make your `@RequestMapping` like: `@RequestMapping("/widgets/getWidget.vm")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `InternalResourceViewResolver` and use `VelocityViewResolver`. Like this

Your `dispatcher.xml` should be:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
    <property name="resourceLoaderPath">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value></value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.vm</value>
    </property>
    <property name="toolboxConfigLocation">
        <value>/WEB-INF/velocity-toolbox.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```